# Stripe is successfully charging clients when CVV and expiration date are incorrect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, stripe-payments

### Context

I have a Next.js project where I want to handle subscription payments through Stripe. To do this I am using the `@stripe/stripe-js` and `@stripe/react-stripe-js` libraries. The problem I'm facing is that when the user enters his card information and either the CVV or the expiration date are erroneous, the transaction succeeds. I'm confused as to why this is happening and want to fix this to avoid frauds from occurring inside my website.

### Code implementation

I have a button in the website that looks like this:

```js
<button onClick={() => handlePayment("price_9GWxvwZT9I0y2hA0wd7J8gec")}>
    Checkout
</button>
```

The function that is invoked from this button creates a Stripe subscription.

```js
const handlePayment = async (price_id) => {
    fetch('https://api.example.com/create_stripe_subscription', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "price_id": price_id,
            "user_email": 'user@example.com',
        })
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            response.json().then(data => {
                router.push(`/checkout?client=${data.client_secret}`)
            });
        }
    })
};
```

The API call [creates a subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create) and returns the [client secret](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret) which is then passed to the checkout page as a query string. If this `handlePayment()` function is successful the checkout page holds the following code.

```js
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
import MetaHead from "@/components/meta-head"
import CheckoutForm from "@/components/checkout-form"

// Call outside of a component’s render to avoid recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);

export default function Checkout() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const clientSecret = router.query.client;

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Checkout</h1>
            {clientSecret && stripePromise && (
                <div>
                    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret: clientSecret }}>
                        <CheckoutForm />
                    </Elements>
                </div >
            )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Here the `CheckoutForm` component holds the following code.

```js
import { useStripe, useElements, PaymentElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function CheckoutForm() {
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();

    const [message, setMessage] = useState(null);
    const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState(false);

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        // Prevent default form submission, this would refresh the page.
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!stripe || !elements) {
            // Stripe.js hasn't yet loaded, make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
            return;
        }

        setIsProcessing(true);

        const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
            // `Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element.
            elements,
            confirmParams: {
                return_url: `${window.location.origin}/admin?load=panel`,
            }
        });

        if (error) {
            setMessage(error.message);
        } else {
            setMessage("Unexpected state...");
        }

        setIsProcessing(false);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <form id="payment-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <PaymentElement />
                    <button disabled={isProcessing} id="submit">
                        Pay now
                    </button>
                </form>
            </div>

            {/* Handle user messaging */}
            {message && (
                <span>{message}</span>
            )}
        </>
    )
};
```

Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Is this in a productive environment or a test environment? Are you testing with real credit card information or the testing cards provided by stripe?

Comment: This is happening in a productive environment, but you need to register a user. I'll move it to an open URL and share this.

Answer (score 0):

## Stripe Solution

I emailed the Stripe Support Team, and they explained the solution. It turns out this is not a bug nor a problem on Stripe's end. I have for you here a summary of the email I got.

> Payments with incorrect CVC were set to be allowed in my account. Nevertheless, you can set a rule to block any payment with incorrect CVC.
>
> Without a specific block rule, the customer’s bank can still approve a charge, even if the CVC or ZIP code (AVS) check fails. Banks take a variety of signals into account in their systems and may see a charge as being legitimate despite the check not passing and then send the charge approval along to Stripe. More details about this in [this article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/charge-succeeded-despite-cvc-or-zip-check-mismatch).
>
> If you'd like to block payments with unverified CVC, you can edit the rules in the *Radar* section of your Stripe Dashboard. You can do this through [this link](https://dashboard.stripe.com/radar/rules). Scroll down to the *Block rules* section, click on the *** in front of the Block if CVC verification fails, click on Enable, then confirm this action.
>
> You can also add custom rules. To do so, click the "+Add Rule" button underneath the *Block* section and enter the applicable code. To learn more about custom rules codes, [check this document](https://stripe.com/docs/radar).

I hope this is helpful to other people; the Stripe Support Team is excellent, and they are fast responders.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the 4242 [test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing) to test your integrations? If so, the transaction will succeed as long as the expiration date is a valid future date, and the cvc is any 3-digit (or 4-digit for Amex) number.

If this problem happens in production, you should reach out to [Stripe support](https://support.stripe.com/contact/email) with relevant PaymentIntent ID, and they will help you.

Comment: This is happening in production with real cards, I'll reach out to Stripe support. Thanks!